# how much memory needed for jekyll process ?

Tags: vps, jekyll

Im going to move my blog to a jekyll blog engine, but i have a small vps and now it has alot of sites hosted, and not so much free memory at this day. And swap is off by default and i cant handle it.

I want to ask you how much memory jekyll process will use ?

Anyone can see ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you didn't get that jekyll is a **static** blog generator, then it won't take memory on your web server at run time. It means that :

- you can generate your site on any machine you want, with ruby and jekyll installed,
- then move the genrated site into the web server, which doesn't need ruby and jekyll installed.

Does it make more sense now ?